# why is my minimax recursion not looping through all possible outcomes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I'm not sure where I'm wrong with my function but it doesn't check every possible out it seems to check a few and I don't know how to fix it here's my code

basic variables

```
const defaultScore = {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0}
const [boardState,setBoardState] = useState(defaultScore)
const winArray = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,6,4]]
const AI = side
const human = (side == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X'
```

a function to copy the current state of the board without changing the actual state

```
const copyBoard=(original :Object,index ?:any, newValue?:any)=>{
            const copiedBoard = {...original} 
            index = Number(index)
            if(index != null && newValue != null){
                copiedBoard[index] = newValue
            }
            return copiedBoard
        }
```

the function for checking end state

```
 const tryWin=(board :Object)=>{
                let win
                let check = true
                for (const i in winArray){
                    const v = winArray[i]                 
                    if(compareWin(board[v[0]],board[v[1]],board[v[2]])){
                        check = false
                        if(board[v[0]] == AI){
                            win = 10
                        }else{
                            win = -10
                        }
                    }  
                }
                if(!Object.values(board).includes(0) && check){
                    win = 0
                } 
                return win
            }
```

the minimax

```
        const miniMax = (board:Object, depth:number, isMax :Boolean ) =>{           
           
            if(typeof(tryWin(board)) == 'number'){
                return tryWin(board)
            }
      
            if(isMax){
                for (const v in board){              
                    if(board[v] === 0){
                        const outcome = -100
                        let simBoard = copyBoard(board,v,AI)
                        const newOutcome = miniMax(simBoard,depth+1,!isMax)
                        return (typeof(newOutcome) == 'undefined') ? outcome : Math.max(outcome,newOutcome) - depth
       
                    }
                }
            }else{
                for (const v in board){
                    if(board[v] === 0){
                        const outcome = 100
                        let simBoard = copyBoard(board,v,human)
                        const newOutcome = miniMax(simBoard,depth+1,!isMax)
                        return (typeof(newOutcome) == 'undefined') ?  outcome : Math.min(outcome,newOutcome) + depth
                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        const AImove =()=>{
            let move
            let bestOutcome = -100
            for(const v in boardState){
                if(boardState[v] === 0){
                    let simBoard = copyBoard(boardState,v,AI)
                    const outcome = miniMax(simBoard,0,true)
                    console.log('move',v,'outcome',outcome)
                    if(outcome > bestOutcome){
                        bestOutcome = outcome
                        move = Number(v)
                    }
                }          
            }
            return {move:move,outcome:bestOutcome}
        }
```

what am I getting wrong?